# Rename columns after pandas.DataFrame.groupby.apply()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply `scipy.stats` to a pandas DataFrame, grouped by a column. I'd like to be able to keep the name of the columns in the resulting DataFrame. Here's what I have so far.

Start with some random data for demonstration.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),
           columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df['category'] = pd.Series(["1","2","3","1","1","3","2","3","1","2"])
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    a           b           c           d           e         category
0   -0.384575   -1.722937   0.868886    -1.843398   -1.659861   1
1   1.170742    -2.732823   0.974790    -0.167318   0.399720    2
2   -0.330587   -0.214645   -0.196441   0.768405    1.256272    3
3   0.961955    -0.270461   -0.226601   1.911941    -0.595420   1
4   0.596214    0.122938    2.420786    0.113196    0.734691    1
```

Here's an example of what I want, using the `sum()` function:

```
grouped = df.groupby('category')
grouped.sum()
```

Output:

```
    a           b           c           d           e
category                    
1   -0.246350   -0.973571   4.525511    2.690969    -2.216404
2   2.238123    -3.794821   -0.457655   -1.248493   -0.342675
3   -1.049097   1.359168    1.125174    0.659131    2.139560
```

Notice that the columns have the correct label. Now for the problem:

```
grouped.apply(kurtosis)
```

Output:

```
category
1    [-1.40177576836, -1.02037807436, -1.1792712163...
2                       [-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5]
3                       [-1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5]
dtype: object
```

Note that this is no longer a DataFrame, and doesn't have column names. So I try to get smart, and output a series with the name specified – but it doesn't work:

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(kurtosis(x), name=x.name))
```

Output:

```
     0          1           2           3           4
category                    
1   -1.401776   -1.020378   -1.179271   -1.384131   -0.984184
2   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000
3   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000   -1.500000
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why that happens (mine raises a `TypeError` instead) but you can use `agg`:

```
df.groupby("category").agg(kurtosis)
Out[16]: 
                a         b         c         d         e
category                                                 
1        -1.18953 -1.013635 -1.756748 -1.167473 -1.271358
2        -1.50000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000
3        -1.50000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000 -1.500000
```

Comment: Thanks! – This worked for most of my functions, and I was able to adapt it as follows for the remaining one: `df.groupby("category").agg(lambda x: kstest(x, 'norm')[1])`. The `[1]` takes only the p-value output from the `kstest` function.